# Laravel 5.4.21 default authentication links does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am following this user manual: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication written for Laravel 5.4

I first created a new Laravel application by issuing:

```
$ laravel new mysite
```

In .env file I changed DB_DATABASE=mysite_db

Then I switched to /Code/mysite directory and issued:

```
$ php artisan make:auth
$ php artisan migrate
```

When I point to http://mysite.app/register I get the message: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." http://mysite.app/login is also the same. I also tried http://mysite.app/auth/register.

Why the default Authentication routing does not work?

---

routes/web.php reads:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Only auth routes dosen't work? Do you have mod rewrite enabled on Apache2?

Comment: I have a site using laravel 5.3 and it works. I am using Homestead so I guess it should be enabled by default.

Comment: Run `php artisan route:clear`, create a custom route and try if it works. :)

Comment: @Troyer, I ran `php artisan route:clear` still no avail.

Comment: Is the route listed when you issue `php artisan route:list --path=login` ?

Comment: Did you get any errors when running those commands? Did you run the commands inside your vagrant environment?

Comment: @linktoahref: yes the route is listed.

Comment: @Christophvh: I couldn't see any error.

Comment: @Ehsan 99% sure is a problem with your Homestead.

Comment: My laravel 5.3 site works well. Maybe I should update something?

Comment: `php artisan --version` gives 5.4.21

Comment: Does it work if you do: mysite.app/public/register ?

Comment: @Christophvh: Unfortunately no.

Comment: @Ehsan, could you post the full error you are getting? Do you have the errors display turned on in your laravel .env configuration file?

Comment: I solved it by upgrading my Homestead.

Comment: @Troyer was right the problem was with an old version of Homestead.

Answer (score 0):

First, run $ `php artisan make:auth`.

Because by default, at least in 5.4, Laravel does not include the Authentication routes and views. Running the command generates them. You'll see it mentioned in the [Laravel Authentication Quickstart](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart).

Comment: Ow, yeah. didnt see the comments early enough. Now looking deeper in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem by myself:

I first issued:

```
$ vagrant box list
```

To find out my downloaded boxes, Then:

```
$ vagrant box remove laravel/homestead
```

Then I upgraded my homestead from version 1.0.1 to 2.1.0:

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

I also upgraded my homestead vagrant environment using:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead2
$ cd Homestead2
$ git checkout v5.2.4
```

After this the authentication routes worked.